# break out of setInterval loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I am coding a game.
I would like to break out of the setInterval loop when a condition is met to display a game over screen. My code :

```
var timer = 0;
var i =0;
fond.onload= function()
{
    timer = setInterval(boucle,50);
    console.log("break");
}

function boucle()
{
    i++;
    if(i===4)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

I never reach the break log because just after the clearInterval, the screen is stuck.
Thank you!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add console.log to boucle and see if 'i' ever == 4, also use ===.  Any other console errors?

Comment: Hello, my code is quite long, I thought that minimising it would help to handle the concept of my question

Comment: impossible to answer since that code should work fine

Comment: @Adam I have no error, I am just stuck. Is it the normal behaviour ?

Comment: @Letchi The code you showed [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/z72smxqk/3/). If your screen gets stuck you probably have an infinite loop somewhere else. But we simply can't help you with that due to the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `fond.onload` represents in your code, but if you want the code to run when the page is loaded you should use `window.onload` or `document.onload`.

`onload` is a global event handler bound to all objects that gets executed when that object is loaded. I presume that in your case `fond` is never loaded as the rest of the code is fine, just never runs. It will run fine if you bind the function to `window.onload`.

You can read up more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)